# Reading specific properties file on specific stages on Bamboo

Tags: java, liquibase, bamboo, properties-file

I have a java web application which uses liquibase db and using bamboo for CI. (I'm kinda new to CI stuff and bamboo)

My question is, I need to read properties files on specific stages. For instance, on test stage I want to read my `test.properties` and on another stage I want to read `other.properties` file.

(Note: This properties files will be read from local directory like `/home/user/configs/config.properties`)

It's also valid for liquibase db changesets. On test stage I want to read my test changesets and on another stage want to read another changesets.

What is the proper way of doing this? How can I tell the bamboo to do the job? I tried to create bamboo tasks for it but I couldn't be successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this goal by using another tool called salt.

You can find more information from [here.](https://saltstack.com/)